# Não consigo retorna a mensagem dizendo se os valores formam um triângulo retângulo

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

int retangulo(int a, int b, int c){


    int maior;

    if(a>b && a>c){// iníco primeira verificação...

        maior = a;

        if( pow(maior,2) == pow(b,2) + pow(c,2) ){

            printf("\n Verdadeiro...");
        }

    }// fim primeira verificação...

    else if(b>a && b>c){// iníco segunda verificação...

            maior = b;

            if( pow(maior,2) == pow(a,2) + pow(c,2) ){

                printf("\n Verdadeiro...");

             }

        }// fim segunda verificação...

        else if(c>a && c>b){// iníco terceira verificação...

                 maior = c;

                if( pow(maior,2) == pow(a,2) + pow(b,2) ){

                    printf("\n Verdadeiro...");

                 }

            }// fim terceira verificação...

            else{

                printf("\n Falso...");
            }
}

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"ptb");

    int l1, l2, l3, X;

    printf("\n Digite quatro valores inteiros:\n");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &l1, &l3, &l3);

    X = retangulo(l1,l2,l3);


    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tome cuidado com comparações de igualdade para variáveis float/double. Como podem ser valores aproximados a comparação pode não ser verdadeira quando você julgar que deva ser. O uso da função round pode eliminar este possível problema.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um debug no seu código e achei os seguintes problemas:

1. Seu `scanf` no método `main()` não está lendo as variáveis devidas. Está lendo `l1`, `l3` e `l3`, quando deveria estar lendo `l1`, `l2`, `l3`; a consequência disso é que o valor `l2` (assumido em `b`) não é lido, e portanto o programa não é capaz de fazer as verificações no método `retangulo()`;
2. O seu `if` aninhado (o que verifica o Teorema de Pitágoras) não possui um caminho no caso da condição ser falsa. Em outras palavras, o programa verifica um dos `if else if`, e uma vez que o código se encontra no `if` aninhado que eu mencionei acima, ele não tem uma escapatória, senão dar um "break" e sair do método, e é por isso que o programa termina sua execução sem imprimir nada. Portanto, para contornar esse problema e obter o resultado esperado de verificação, é necessário que a mensagem de "Falso..." esteja dentro do `if` aninhado.

**Nota:** O programa só executará o `else { printf("\n Falso..."); }` que você fez lá no final (antes do `main()`) quando nenhuma das verificações de `if (a > b && a > c) {}`, etc., for verdadeira.

Vou deixar abaixo o fix do seu código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

int retangulo(int a, int b, int c){


    int maior;

    if(a>b && a>c){// iníco primeira verificação...

        maior = a;

        if(pow(maior,2) == pow(b,2) + pow(c,2)){

            printf("\n Verdadeiro...");
        }
        else{

            printf("\n Falso...");
        }

    }// fim primeira verificação...

    else if(b > a && b > c){// iníco segunda verificação...

        maior = b;

        if(pow(maior,2) == pow(a,2) + pow(c,2)){

            printf("\n Verdadeiro...");

        }
        else{

            printf("\n Falso...");
        }

    }// fim segunda verificação...

    else if(c > a && c > b){// iníco terceira verificação...

        maior = c;

        if(pow(maior,2) == pow(a,2) + pow(b,2)){

            printf("\n Verdadeiro...");

        }
        else{

            printf("\n Falso...");
        }

    }// fim terceira verificação...


}

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"ptb");

    int l1, l2, l3, X;

    printf("\n Digite quatro valores inteiros:\n");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &l1, &l2, &l3);

    X = retangulo(l1,l2,l3);

    return 0;
}
```